# Running an exploded spring-boot jar from command line

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jersey

I'm looking to run an exploded spring-boot jar.
Currently I'm doing

```
jar xf app.jar
java -cp /lib/*:/ com/domain/module/Main
```

which seems to begin the app startup, but invariably stops on

> [restartedMain] INFO  c.a.a.spring.MetricsJersey2Config - Registering InstrumentedResourceMethodApplicationListener for jersey2 with MetricRegistry: com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry@43fee23e

The next line I'd **usually** expect to see is

> [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor - Initializing ExecutorService

Running the app using

```
java -jar app.jar
```

works fine, but for reasons I need to run it exploded.

Is there anything I'm missing in trying to run a spring-boot app this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this by running:

```sh
java -cp /lib/*:/ com.domain.module.Main
```

Rather than:

```sh
java -cp /lib/*:/ com/domain/module/Main
```

Answer (score 2):

In July 2023, with Java 19 and SpringBoot 3.0.6.

I exploded my SringBoot jar.
This command line started the app.

`java -cp "BOOT-INF/lib/*:." org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher`
`

Answer (score 0):

i'm facing this problem too ! don't forget to copy your clashpath of your .class in main package and spring boot org.springframework package, for example :`-cp ./com/*:./org/*`